# QLDB Transaction Isolation

Tags: amazon-qldb

I was looking at the sample code here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/qldb/latest/developerguide/getting-started.python.step-5.html, and noticed that the three functions `get_document_id_by_gov_id`, `is_secondary_owner_for_vehicle` and `add_secondary_owner_for_vin` are executed separately in three `driver.execute_lambda` calls. So if there are two concurrent requests that are trying to add a secondary owner, would this trigger a serialization conflict for one of the requests?

The reason I'm asking is that I initially thought we would have to run all three functions within the same `execute_lambda` call in order for the serialization conflict to happen since each `execute_lambda` call uses one session, which in turn uses one transaction. If they are run in three `execute_lambda` calls, then they would be spread out into three transactions, and QLDB wouldn't be able to detect a conflict. But it seems like my assumption is not true, and the only benefit of batching up the function calls would just be better performance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got an answer from a QLDB specialist so going to answer my own question: the operations should have been wrapped in a single transaction so my original assumption was actually true. They are going to update the code sample to reflect this.

Comment: I'm new to QLDB. The code is still having the 3 separate calls. Just to be sure, the right solution is to run the 3 statements in the same `execute_lamba` call, so they run in the same transaction, right?

Comment: @dd. Yes that's right.